# Como calcular um valor enquanto o usuário digita em uma aplicação Android?

Tags: java, android

Olá pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que o usuário deve digitar uma quantidade e o valor unitário e o aplicativo calcula o total a pagar. Mas se apagar todo o valor que está nos campos o programa aborta. Como posso corrigir isso?

IncluirProdutoActivity.java

```
public class IncluirProdutoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incluir_produto);

    final EditText quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantidade);
    final EditText precoUnitario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.preco_unitario);
    final EditText valorTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor_total);



    quantidade.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Float preco = Float.valueOf(precoUnitario.getText().toString());
            Float q = Float.valueOf(s.toString());
            Float total = q * preco;
            valorTotal.setText(total.toString());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando apaga o valor nos campos a string retornada por `precoUnitario.getText().toString()` é vazia(`""`).

Uma string vazia não pode ser convertida para um Float, sendo por isso gerado um erro.

Para resolver deve verificar essa situação e fazer o cálculo usando o valor zero:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Float preco = 0;
    Float q = 0;

    String stringPreco = precoUnitario.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!stringPreco.equals("")){
        preco = Float.valueOf(stringPreco);
    }

    String stringS = s.toString().trim();
    if(!stringS.equals("")){   
        q = Float.valueOf(stringS);
    }         

    Float total = q * preco;
    valorTotal.setText(total.toString());
}
```

Note que deve também garantir que o usuário apenas digita números nos EditText.
Inclua na declaração dos EditText o seguinte:

```
android:text="0" 
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Answer (score -2):

Aparentemente o erro está nesse trecho:

```
valorTotal.setText(total.toString());
```

invés de converter dessa forma tenta alterar está linha para:

```
valorTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```